# Implementar canActivate no funciona si retorno un valor dentro del subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un guard en Angular 7 para verificar si está loggeado o no un usuario. Tanto el back como la petición funciona correctamente, sin embargo no puedo controlarlo dentro del subscribe. Este es el código que desarrollé

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { StorageService } from '../storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private _login: LoginService,
               private _router: Router,
               private _session: StorageService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    this._login.isLogged()
    .subscribe(
      // Si la respuesta es un código HTTP 204, entonces está autorizado
      () => true,

      // Si la respuesta es un código HTTP 401 entonces NO está autorizado
      () => {
        this._session.deleteData();
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      });
  }
}
```

El problema es que el `return` del `.subscribe` no regresa el true o false al `canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean` no sé como hacer para regresar ese Booleano

Me aparece este error

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

intenté hasta asignar el valor del `subscribe` a una variable para hacer `return` al final de `canActivate()` sin embargo es una función asíncrona por lo que termina de ejecutar el código y no espera la respuesta, reitero, todo funciona excelente tanto las respuestas del backend, como la función `isLogged()` la cual retorna el `Observable` al que me estoy suscribiendo en el guard.

Que puedo hacer?

También intenté esta función

```
return this._login.isLogged().pipe( map( (data: any) => {
  if( data.auth ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this._session.deleteData();
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
})
)
```

Y ahora ya funciona únicamente si hay un HTTP 200, no puedo controlar el código 401

Comment: ¿Qué cosa contiene `data.auth`?

Comment: un true, tuve que modificar el backend. Estoy usando nodejs, y ya un middleware que valida si esta autorizado, el segundo ejemplo fue un error. No debería intentar implementarlo así

Comment: La respuesta del server con código `200` o `204` retorna algo en el body?

Comment: No retorna nada, por eso no lo evalúo en el subscribe, es sencillo, si es 204, esta aútorizado, si hay error, no lo está.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Ya actualicé el ejemplo. Tu pregunta era algo confusa en ese sentido

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No debes usar `subscribe` dentro de un guard porque lo que este necesita es un `Observable` como tal y lo que te retorna llamar a esta función es un [`Subscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ffc4e688fa83cb44bff7e5deacc4063f8ea1e2fa/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L19) que es el que contiene el método `unsubscribe` y para que el guard internamente pueda registrar la emisión de valores lo que necesita es poder acceder el mismo al `subscribe` que viene incluido en la interfaz del `Observable`.

Puedes usar el operador `map` para transformar el valor que recibes al ejecutar tu función `isLogged()` y retornar uno de los valores que [pueden procesar los guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). De manera ideal estos valores deberían ser `true` si está permitido el acceso o un [`UrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) si no lo está. Por ejemplo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { StorageService } from '../storage.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private _login: LoginService,
               private _router: Router,
               private _session: StorageService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean | Observable<UrlTree> | UrlTree {

    return this._login.isLogged()
        .pipe(
            // Si la petición es exitosa se puede proceder
            map(() => true),
            // Si la peticion tiene un error de estado >= 400 se dirige al login
            catchError(() => {
               this._session.deleteData();
               return of(this._router.createUrlTree(['/login']))
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Los `UrlTree` estan soportados a partir de Angular >= [7.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-21), pueden ser creados fácilmente con la función [`createUrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree)  y se usan como una mejor alternativa a tener que escribir `navigate` acompañado de `return false`. Por ejemplo estos códigos *dentro de un guard son equivalentes*:

```
this._router.navigate(['/login']);
return false;
```

a

```
return this._router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
```

Si usas una versión inferior a la 7.1 tendrás que usar la primera alternativa pero en ningún caso debes retornar solamente false sin navegar pues el usuario no se enterará que ha ocurrido un error.

Aquí dejo una explicación mas detallada de los operadores

```
map(() => true)
```

equivale a

```
map(result => {
    return true;
})
```

Cualquiera que sea el resultado si el status code del http está en el rango de los `200` el guard recibirá un valor `true` y procederá la navegación a la ruta solicitada

```
catchError(() => {
    this._session.deleteData();
    return of(this._router.createUrlTree(['/login']))
})
```

Si el código de estado del resultado es `>=400` llamas al método `deleteData` y retornas un observable usando `of` que producirá un valor estático y luego completará. Este valor estático es el `UrlTree` que espera el guard para saber a donde debe dirigirse.

Comment: Es una respuesta muy interesante y estructurada. Me puedes decir en que casos se utiliza en `of()`

Comment: Necesito ejecutar `this._session.deleteData();` en el `catchError()` donde pongo ese pedazo de código?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Actualizé la respuesta para incluir la llamada a `deleteData()`. El problema con el `of` en este caso es que el manejo de errores se puede hacer como parte del `subscribe` como lo tienes en tu pregunta y que no puedes usar por las razones antes expuestas y con el `catchError` que hace la misma función pero requiere obligatoriamente que se devuelva un observable al cual subscribirse. El `of` es un operador que te genera un nuevo observable que emite los valores que le pases y luego completa, en este caso el valor generado es el `UrlTree` que necesita el guard.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Para aprender más sobre RXjs puedes ir aquí https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el operador **map** para retornar, por ejemplo

```
export class DataComponent{
  someMethod() {
    return this.http.get(path).map(res => {
      return res.json();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que ese código funcionaría en Angular 4 o 2, desde Angular 5 la la clase HttpClient se encarga de desserializar los JSON automáticamente

Answer (score 2):

Añadiendo el `return` y usando `pipe` avanzaste en la dirección correcta, pero te faltó gestionar los errores, parece que eliminaste esa parte del código:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

  return this._login.isLogged().pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      if( data.auth ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this._session.deleteData();
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      this._session.deleteData();
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: No lo eliminé, simplemente no sabía que el `pipe()``podía hacer eso

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar de hacer lo siguiente

Te suscribes al servicio y capturas el resultado en una variable

```
  this.servicio.metodoServicio().subscribe(
        result => {
              // puedes validar que resultado tiene result , este variable guarda lo que llegue del servidor
```

En tu caso seria asi

```
this._login.isLogged().subscribe(
      // Si la respuesta es un código HTTP 204, entonces está autorizado
      result => {
           // debes validar la estructura de datos que llega en el result
           if(result.code) {
            // aqui returnas el true
           } else {
               this._session.deleteData();
               this._router.navigate(['/login']);
               return false;
           }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que el subscribe no retorna lo que está como su parámetro, sino que el subscribe retorna un objeto Subscription.

Podrías retornar solamente `this._login.isLogged()` y suscribirte en la parte del código que invoca a `canActivate()`.