# Ejecutar el código una vez la suscripción me haya devuelto un resultado - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema en un canActivate de una ruta.
Quiero que una vez tenga la respuesta de la llamada a una api, se ejecute el if. Porque sino siempre es false, dado que se ejecuta al mismo tiempo la llamad la api que el if.

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  const token = this.userService.getToken();

  this.userService.deserializeToken(token).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.identity = response;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );

  if (this.identity && this.identity.role === 2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Tambien he probado este codigo pero da error dado que me pide que ponga como tipo de dato que devolvemos tiene que ser any o void.

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  const token = this.userService.getToken();

  this.userService.deserializeToken(token).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.identity = response;
      if (this.identity && this.identity.role === 2) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  );
}
```

Al final lo que quiero de alguna manera es hacerlo asincrono. Pero no se como
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Implementar canActivate no funciona si retorno un valor dentro del subscribe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274711/implementar-canactivate-no-funciona-si-retorno-un-valor-dentro-del-subscribe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu segundo trozo de código es que el return es para la función anónima. Es equivalente a

```
canActivate(): boolean {
  const token = this.userService.getToken();

  const subscriber = response => {
      this.identity = response;
      if (this.identity && this.identity.role === 2) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    };

  this.userService.deserializeToken(token).subscribe(subscriber)
    ,
    error => {
      ...
    }
  );
}
```

Pero en realidad un guard puede devolver un Observable, así que puedes transformar ese código a algo como:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  const token = this.userService.getToken();

  const mapper = response => {
      this.identity = response;
      if (this.identity && this.identity.role === 2) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    };

  return this.userService.deserializeToken(token).pipe((map(mapper));
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Me ha funcionado