# Problema angular guard con suscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

tengo un guard con su metodo CanLoad, que llama a una funcion, esta funcion se suscribe a un servicio.
El problema es que me llega undefined cuando llamo a la funcion en el servicio y creo qeu es por el suscribe.

La funcion es this.checkLogged(), el else de la funcion, el cual retorna false directamente,si llega cuando llamo a la funcion en canLoad, pero cuando ingresa en el if, es decir,cuando se comunica al servicio y se suscribe, el response (que retorna true) y el error (que retorna false) no llegan cuando llamo a la funcion en canLoad.

**Ni si quiera la variable "prueba" llega a tener valor, es como que lo que esta dentro del suscribe no sale para afuera**

```js
  canLoad(
    route: import('@angular/router').Route,
    segments: import('@angular/router').UrlSegment[]
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    // console.log(this.checkLogged());
    return this.checkLogged();
  }

    checkLogged() {
let token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
if (!!token) {
  let prueba:boolean
  this.loggedService.isLogged(token).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
       prueba = true
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return false
    }
  )
  console.log(prueba);

} else {
  sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
  this.route.navigate(['login']);
  return false;
}
  }
```

Comment: El problema es que estás modificando un valor de manera a asíncrona. Cuando modificas el dato (entiendo que `prueba`) en `this.loggedService.isLogged(token).subscribe(...)`, la modificación y validación se realizan dentro de una función callback (`(response) => { ... }`).

Comment: @KBeDev que me recomendas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Implementar canActivate no funciona si retorno un valor dentro del subscribe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274711/implementar-canactivate-no-funciona-si-retorno-un-valor-dentro-del-subscribe)

Comment: @PabloLozano @ me ayudan con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454105/angular-cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefined

Answer (score 1):

Tal como menciona @JhonRayo99, una alternativa es usar una promesa. Aunque la interfaz `Observable` posee ya un método integrado para hacer esto, el cual es `toPromise()`. Aquí un ejemplo alternativo al uso de la clase `Promise`:

```
async checkLogged(): Promise<boolean> {
  let token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  if (!!token) {
    let prueba: boolean; // Se declara con "valor" indefinido
    try {
      const response = await this.loggedService.isLogged(token).toPromise();
      console.log(response);
      prueba = true;
    } catch (reason) {
      console.error(reason);
      prueba = false;
    }
    return prueba;
  } else {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.route.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Me funciono, te super agradezco !