# ¿Cómo obtener una respuesta asíncrona en AuthGuard en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asincronismo

Me estoy volviendo un poco loco. Estoy implementando un AuthGuard en mi proyecto de Angular, pero tengo un problema, y es que tengo un método que hace una llamada a mi API, para verificar que un token que le paso es válido o no.

Este método devuelve o un estado *OK* o un estado *NOK*, dependiendo de si es válido o no.

El método que llama al servidor lo tengo en *auth.service.ts*, es el siguiente:

```
  tokenValid = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(null);

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService) { }

  loggedIn() {
    this.backendService.verifyToken().subscribe(
      resp => {
        if (resp.status === "OK") {
          this.tokenValid.next(true);
        } else {
          this.tokenValid.next(false);
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.error("An error has ocurred");
      }
    );
  }
```

Este método se llama desde el *auth.guard.ts* de la siguiente forma con el *canActivate*:

```
  canActivate() {
    this.authService.loggedIn();
    
    if (this.authService.tokenValid.value) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

El problema es que como es un método asíncrono, en el *if-else* del *canActivate*, siempre llega con valor NULL.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Esto responde tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/432579/158388

Comment: Exacto, responde a mi pregunta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El interfaz CanActivate acepta devolver un `Observable<boolean>`, no sólo `boolean`. Puedes reescribir tu servicio como:

```
loggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.backendService.verifyToken().pipe(
    map(resp => resp.status === "OK"),
    catchError(_ => {
        console.error("An error has ocurred");
        return of(false);
      }
    )
  });
}
```

Con lo que tu guard quedaría

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.loggedIn();
}
```